# error: no C99 compiler found, eudev requires a C99 compiler

Tags: error-handling, makefile, compiler-errors, c99, buildroot

I executed the command "make" after the configurations on the menuconfig of buildroot and then this error appeared.
It appears when i enable eudev.

Can someone help me???

when i do gcc --std=c99
the output is:
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

Comment: While in menuconfig, you probably changed something related to the toolchain. In that case, you need to do a mlmake clean before doing make

Answer (score 0):

You must inform your c++ or c file in the console:
gcc --std=c99 you_source_code.cpp

If you give more information about what you are doing will help understand your problem.